# Aspiring to Build a Space Rover from Scratch – Where to Begin?

Tags: nasa, rovers, engineering, robotics, lunar-rover

What fundamental concepts, beginner-friendly resources, or online courses would you recommend for someone starting with little to no background in robotics?

**At first,
I want to build a an autonomous wheeled rover which can navigate (using sensors) on rough surfaces and pick sample (with attached gripper on chasis) and safely drop it to a position marked with circle of any colour.
It only communicate using Radio Frequency of legal range. No wire should be outside , it is totally remotely controlled. Power source should be battery.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to space SE. Currently your question is very broad - you yourself include a request for information on background concepts. As such it will probably be closed here as too broad. Suggest breaking it down into segments. The elements relating to building a vehicle actually capable of operating in space are on topic here, while the nuts and bolts of building and programing would be better on Arudino and electronics stacks.

Comment: In terms for where to begin a common path for the electronics part of things starts with Arduino https://www.arduino.cc/ and cheaper copies. Though it is by no means the 'best' package it is widely available, relatively cheap and compatible rover hardware can be purchased as kits (search 'arduino compatible rover kit'). In terms of tips, always buy at least three of a part so you can afford to break one and still have a spare. If you can only afford to buy one of a part, you cannot really afford the part so try to find another way.

Comment: Hi there - welcome. Be aware this site is very different to discussion forums. Please read our [about] and [ask] pages for guidance as to how the site works, and then browse the questions and answers so you can see what sort of questions work well here, and what sort of answers you will get.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* You can ask as many (good) questions as you like in as many different SE sites as you like - for example of the [almost 200 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) to choose from there is also [Robotics SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/). The advice above is good, first read through questions here tagged [tag:rovers] or more specific tags like [tag:lunar-rover], [tag:mars-exploration-rover] or [tag:mars-science-laboratory] or [tag:curiosity] or [tag:perseverance] and see if some of these help.

Comment: You could ask a [tag:reference-request] question like "Are there any introductory 'how to build a space rover' resources that cover the engineering challenges in a systematic way?" In that question don't get detailed or ask multiple questions, just ask for resources. If you have specific engineering aspects to ask about, ask something specific. It's often helpful to ask one question, wait for an answer or two, then base your next question on answers from the previous. Don't ask the same question in both sites, but your questions in one site can (and sometimes should) link to those in the other

Comment: There are some basic robotics texts posted at Northwestern University. Go for it!  https://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/2/2a/Park-lynch.pdf https://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/7/7f/MR.pdf